# Explain Python Docs Section 4.4

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am going through the Python docs and can't make sense of what is going on in section 4.4

```
for n in range(2, 10):
    for x in range(2, n):
        if n % x == 0:
            print(n, 'equals', x, '*', n//x)
            break
    else:
        print(n, 'is a prime number')
```

The main issue I am having is understanding what gets assigned to n and x in the first iteration of these loops (maybe I don't fully understand nested loops) but I would assume in the first iteration we should get something like:

```
for 2(n) in range(2,10):
    for 2(x) in range(2, 2(n)):
        if 2 % 2 == 0
```

But this is not happening ( I know 2 is a prime number), but I am not getting why this is not the behavior occurring. Appreciate the help in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your confusion is not about the nested loop, but the `range` function.

`range(2, 2)` is an empty range, because it is exclusive of the endpoint.

To illustrate: `list(range(3)) == [0, 1, 2]`.

As a note: when iterating through an empty range, nothing happens. So, for example, the following code will not produce an error or print anything:

```
for i in range(0):
    print('Nothing here')
    raise ValueError
```

Therefore, when `n` is 2, the for loop `for x in range(2, 2)` does nothing. `x` does not take the value `None` or any other value. If you attempt to convert an empty range to a `list`, it will simply return `[]`, the empty `list`.

The `for` loop does a set of actions once *for* every element in some collection. When the collection is empty, or has 0 elements, that set of actions is done 0 times.

Comment: I know that it excludes the endpoint and is empty range (ran it in terminal a few times), but I guess what I don't know is what the n % x looks like for the first iteration?

Comment: The first values of `n` and `x` are 3 and 2 respectively. This is because `range(2, 2)` is empty, so the outer loop reaches its next iteration, which gives a value of 3 for `n`. `x` then iterates through the range `(2, 3)`, which yields only the value 2.

Comment: Ok, so I believe I understand this now. So this means, Python has something already set up to handle 2 % None (or blank?) i.e. instead of throwing some type of error it just skips to the else statement in this case.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand your question better now. I will edit my answer.